# Consultar valor a objetos anidados

Tags: c#, linq

espero explicarme bien. Estoy recuperando los datos de una tienda Online(Woocommerce)  en un proyecto .Net.
Esta me devuelve una lista de objetos `Order`, una de las propiedades de este objeto es un `array` de objetos "`meta_data`" estos tiene 3 propiedades "`id`" "`key`" "`value`".

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta que me devuelva todas las `Orders` que en `meta_data` tienen un objeto cuya propiedad `key="Transferred"` y la propiedad `value="yes"`, pero os juro que no se como hacerlo mediante una consulta.
¿Me podéis ayudar por favor?

Comment: Coloca algo de codigo, donde se pueda ver la estructura del metodo, lo que intentaste hacer, a que tabla se llama, etc. si no es complicado hacerte un ejemplo basado en la nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto debería servirte:

```
    public List<Order> ConsultaAObjetosAnidados(List<Order> input)
    {
        var res = from o in input
                  from omd in o._OrderMetaData
                  where omd.key == "trans" && omd.value
                  select o;

        return res.ToList();
    }
```

Comprobaciones básicas:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ConsultaAObjetosAnidados_Devuelve_0_1()
    {
        Order Order1 = new Order()
        {
            OrderNo = 1,
            _OrderMetaData = new List<OrderMetaData>()
        };

        Order1._OrderMetaData.Add(new OrderMetaData()
        {
            id = 1,
            key = "no_trans",
            value = true
        });

        List<Order> input = new List<Order>();

        input.Add(Order1);

        Assert.IsTrue(_csharpfunctions.ConsultaAObjetosAnidados(input).Count == 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ConsultaAObjetosAnidados_Devuelve_1_1()
    {
        Order Order1 = new Order()
        {
            OrderNo = 1,
            _OrderMetaData = new List<OrderMetaData>()
        };

        Order1._OrderMetaData.Add(new OrderMetaData()
        {
            id = 1,
            key = "trans",
            value = true
        });

        List<Order> input = new List<Order>();

        input.Add(Order1);

        var res = _csharpfunctions.ConsultaAObjetosAnidados(input);

        Assert.IsTrue(res.Count == 1);
    }
```